# Pascal - Using procedure before it's defined

Tags: function, pascal, procedure

I have a piece of code that, very simplified, looks like this

```
program helloworld;
a:integer;

procedure alpha;
begin
writeln('This is procedure alpha');
beta;
end;

procedure beta;
begin
writeln('This is procedure beta');
alpha;
end;

begin
readln(a);
if a=1 then alpha;
if a=2 then beta;
end.
```

That is of course an example, but you get what am I trying to say. I know where the error is - I'm trying to use a procedure, that has not been defined yet -, but what I'm trying to figure out is how to make pascal "ignore" it until it really becomes a problem (here it's not a problem, because procedure beta is defined later)?

TLDR; How to use procedure, that has not yet been defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pascal only knows about what has already been defined, so you need a `forward` declaration before any of the procedures :

```
procedure beta; forward;

procedure alpha;
begin
    writeln('This is procedure alpha');
    beta;
end;

procedure beta;
begin
    writeln('This is procedure beta');
    alpha;
end;
```

However, note that your code will create an infinite loop of calls that will generate either an *stack overflow* (quite appropriately) or an infinite loop, depending on your compiler.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what solves my problem. 
As I said, the code is more complicated than that and every procedure contains a IF..THEN tree, so infinite loop won't happen.