# How to do when procedure A need procedure B and procedure B need procedure A inside a DPR

Tags: delphi

Inside a DPR I have

```
procedure A;
begin
  ...
  B;
  ...
end;

procedure B;
begin
  ...
  A;
  ...
end;
```

How to handle such case inside a DPR? inside a normal unit it's quite easy I just need to declare both procedures in the `interface` section of the unit, but inside a dpr how to do as their is no interface section.

Comment: That looks ripe for a stack overflow.

Comment: Other Qs about this: [Using procedure before it's defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20776557/4299358) and [Call a procedure from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41551355/4299358) and [Call one procedure in another, that was declared before it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61289609/4299358). @FreddieBell The dots/ellipsis could also stand for conditions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use a [forward declaration](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions_(Delphi)#Forward_and_Interface_Declarations):

```pascal
procedure B; forward;

procedure A;
begin
  if 1 + 1 = 3 then
    B;
end;

procedure B;
begin
  if 1 + 1 = 3 then
    A;
end;
```

(Of course, forward declarations can also be used in the implementation section of units, so you don't need to pollute the unit's interface just to make two implementation-section routines know of each other.)